# Pair users with smallest difference values with PHP / Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, logic

I've an array with name and some value like this :

```
$users = array(
    "name one"=>"2",
    "name two"=>"5.5",
    "name three"=>"8",
    "name four"=>"7",
    "name five"=>"2.5", 
    "name six"=>"3"
 );
```

Now I want to make 3 pairs from it but both pairs value must be closest like example answer will :

```
name three pair with name four
name one pair with name five
name two pair with name six
```

I can't find any function in php or in javascript for making pairs like this or any related useful function for it.

Please let me know if there's any function available for same or similar thing or any custom codes to achieve it

Comment: What a logic to combine that pairs?

Comment: @splash58 actually that value is timezone so I want if we can make pairs then their timezone must not have too much difference like if my timezone is 5.5 and someone else is 10 something then it will be hard to get connected so I want pair as per their timezone and minimum time difference between pairs

Comment: How do you want to choose that `name five` pairs with `name one` and not with `name six`? it's the same delta? also, can one element be in 2 different pairs?

Comment: Do you want the pairs to be strings? Inside another array?

Comment: @Kaddath yes `name five` can be pair with any between `name one` or `name six` as difference are same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only logic I can see is that they are the values that is the closest.
If that is the case then you can asort() the array to preserve keys and sort on value.
Then use array_chunk on 2 with third parameter true to preserve keys.

```
$users = array("name one"=>"2","name two"=>"5.5","name three"=>"8","name four"=>"7","name five"=>"2.5","name six"=>"3");

asort($users);
$users = array_chunk($users,2,true);

var_dump($users);
```

This returns:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name one"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["name five"]=>
    string(3) "2.5"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name six"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["name two"]=>
    string(3) "5.5"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name four"]=>
    string(1) "7"
    ["name three"]=>
    string(1) "8"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/7SR7C

---

Made it!

First look at first and last item if they are closer than first and second, if they are then add them to the new list using array_splice (which will remove them from the original array).
Then just merge it with the array_chunk.

```
asort($users);
$keys = array_keys($users);

if(end($users) + $users[$keys[0]] < $users[$keys[1]]-$users[$keys[0]]){
    $new[0][$keys[0]] = array_splice($users,0,1);
    $new[0][end($keys)] = array_splice($users,-1);

}

$new = array_merge($new, array_chunk($users,2,true));


var_dump($new);
```

https://3v4l.org/739TZ

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name one"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["name one"]=>
      string(3) "-11"   // <--- see here
    }
    ["name six"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["name six"]=>    // <--- see here
      string(2) "12"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name two"]=>
    string(3) "5.5"
    ["name four"]=>
    string(1) "7"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name three"]=>
    string(1) "8"
    ["name five"]=>
    string(1) "9"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is perfection. (yeah it doesn't take much to impress me :P)

Comment: Amazing I can accept answer after 4 mins. as per stackoverflow but amazing thanks :)

Comment: Now that OP has clarified it's timezones this will end up linking a -11 with a -6, instead of -11 with +12.

Comment: @MohitBumb Now I'm pleased with my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas :)